# Making data appear from a dropdown list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges

I'm trying to create a sheet that allows me to compare four different properties I'm considering taking a mortgage out on. It contains ranges where I input data (property value, deposit percentage etc) for each of the four properties, and then this feeds into four property displays below which shows me my monthly outgoings for each property.

I'm looking for a way to only see one data input range at a time, using a dropdown to access it. So I could select "Property 1" from the dropdown, it would bring up my Property 1 data input range, I could add the relevant information, and then select Property 2 and do the same etc.

I've tried creating each input range as a named range, and then using =IF to call them like this:

=IF(C8="Property 1",Property_one)

But this just brings up #VALUE! and the error "An array value could not be found."

Any help would be appreciated! [Here's a copy of the sheet I've been working on](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ikgRZN361OyN2dUXqjVO0JfZMUrLbfSUVj-VszcDy_w/edit?usp=sharing) – you can see where I've been faffing around with the =IF function at the bottom.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your VALUE error cell within your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(C8="Property 1", Property_one, ))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(IF(C8="Property 1", Property_one, 
       IF(C8="Property 2", Property_two, 
       IF(C8="Property 3", Property_three, 
       IF(C8="Property 4", Property_four, )))))
```